# Rで文字列の日付データをDate型に変換したい

Tags: python, r

文字列の日付データをDate型に変換したいのですが、以下のようなエラーが出ました。
エラーコードの指している事がどういう事なのかがわからずに困っています。

実行コード

```
asp <- asp %>%
  select(date,genre_name,amount,device_type)
asp$date <- 
  as.Date(asp$date)
```

エラーコード

```
strptime(x, ff) でエラー:  入力文字列が長すぎます
```

入力文字列
date
1 2021-11-01 00:04:00
2 2021-11-01 00:27:00
3 2021-11-01 00:26:00
4 2021-11-01 00:04:00
5 2021-11-01 00:36:00
6 2021-11-01 00:08:00

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 入力文字列が何かを書いた方が回答がつくかと思います。たとえば、`as.Date(paste(rep("A", 1001), sep = "", collapse = ""))`であれば、確かに`Error in strptime(xx, ff, tz = "GMT") : input string is too long`のようなエラーとなります。[(Wandbox)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lMy40o41NEtIAyfi) [(GitHub)](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/90f423a7ffa2c0d069e6fafe2975983c50f98c9c/src/main/Rstrptime.h#L1296)

Comment: 再現可能なコードを提示していただけないでしょうか？またエラーメッセージは上記で全てでしょうか？

Comment: tuedaさんご回答ありがとうございます。入力文字列も書き加えてみます。

Comment: merinoさんご回答ありがとうございます。書き加えたものが再現可能なコードになっているか分からないのですが、これ以外はデータ読み込みのコードしかありません。また、エラーメッセージは上記で全てです。

Comment: もしかして`日付`が欲しいと言いつつ時分秒も含めた文字列を渡しているのでは？ `Date型`が欲しいのなら文字列から年月日だけを切り出して渡すか、時分秒も含めたデータが欲しいのなら`日時クラス`に変換する`as.POSIXct`か`as.POSIXlt`を使う必要がありそうです。[時系列データ|R で時系列データを取り扱う方法](https://stats.biopapyrus.jp/r/basic/time-series.html), [R Language Dateクラス](https://learntutorials.net/ja/r/topic/9015/), [R Language 日時クラス（POSIXctおよびPOSIXlt）](https://learntutorials.net/ja/r/topic/9027/), [［R］文字列を日付に簡単に変換する](http://goldenstate.cocolog-nifty.com/blog/2014/12/r-bbe9.html)

Comment: @kunifさんご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘通り、日付ではなく時分秒も含めたデータを渡していました。日時クラスに変換してみます。

Answer (score 0):

この種のデータ整理は、`lubridate` に頼ることを強くおすすめします。

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, lubridate)

> as_datetime("2021-11-01 00:04:00")
[1] "2021-11-01 00:04:00 UTC"

> as_datetime("2021-11-01 00:04:00", tz = "Asia/Tokyo")
[1] "2021-11-01 00:04:00 JST"
```

`as.date()` でなく `as_date()` (.でなく_)な事にご注意ください。

殆どのケースで、勝手に最適にパースしてくれて便利です。